# How do i combine a horizontal bar graph with a line chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to use combination charts to show horizontal bar chart along with line chart.

But the line i want should be same as the way it is shown in the column chart.

The line chart should not be inverted along the axis when the other series is converted to bar chart.

How can i achieve this ?

[line_bar_chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dzwW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine line and x-range series types:

```
    series: [{
        type: 'xrange',
        ...
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ex2a8o70/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series

Comment: this solution seems like a workaround where both x1,x2 have to be manually calculated especially if the bar involves some negative values
isn't there a setting where we can just have bar graph use one axis and the line graph use the same common yaxis ( which is the xaxis of the bar graph?)

Comment: Your design is not a standard one, so it requires some custom solution. A bar chart is just an inverted column chart and it affects the way a line series are drawn. You can calculate all data programmatically. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jkdybzrq/